# How do I use Boto3 and Python to subscribe a lambda function to a DynamoDB stream?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-dynamodb-streams

How do I use Boto3 and Python to subscribe an AWS Lambda function to an AWS DynamoDB Stream?

Subscribing a Lambda function to a DynamoDB stream is straight-forward enough. However, it's not clear how to do this with code.

I need do it in code because I have to do it about 60 times.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `create_event_source_mapping` from boto3

```
response = client.create_event_source_mapping(
    EventSourceArn=<your stream arn>
    FunctionName='name of function',
    Enabled=True|False,
    BatchSize=123,
    StartingPosition='TRIM_HORIZON'|'LATEST'|'AT_TIMESTAMP',
    StartingPositionTimestamp=datetime(2015, 1, 1)
)
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_event_source_mapping

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html#Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.SNSTopic